# Background image wrong position in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

My site design requires a background image running across the top of the page.  You can see what it is supposed to look like in [this screenshot](http://dansdemos.info/clips/good.png). [Link to my site](http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/WorldClothingCorp_QA/).

Unfortunately, I used Firefox to check my work while putting this together.  I used FireFox, because it has Firebug.  The site looks right in Firefox, but wrong in Safari, Chrome, and IE.  In Safari, Chrome, and IE, the background body wrapper background image is below the menu.  [Example screenshot](http://dansdemos.info/clips/IE10.png) where background at top is wrong.

Is there an easy fix to the background image, so it will work in all browsers, or do I have to take a few steps backward to fix some basic problems in my markup?

Comment: Can you show your markup (HTML, CSS, etc) for display of the image? It's kind of hard to help without knowing what you did.

Comment: Why are you giving us screenshots & not just giving us the link?: http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/WorldClothingCorp_QA/

Comment: Sorry, my bad... here is the link to the site:  http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/WorldClothingCorp_QA/  Thank you for responding.

Comment: Evidently, based on the related questions coming up, and the lack of answers on them, this is a common issue without too much in the way of a general answer.  When I get an answer, I will put it up.  In the meantime, thank you to the people who responded and edited my question.

Comment: Can you at least tell us which of the gigantic number of stylesheet files the code for the background is in?

Comment: LOL... yes, I can do that.  Thanks for the hint about isolating the problem better when asking a question.  Part of the problem is the style setting the background is a in a style tag on the page instead of in a linked stylesheet, so finding it through Firebug is hard.  I'll fix that before asking another question.  In the meantime, the style setting the background image is this:

 #wrapper{
  background-image: url(http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/WorldClothingCorp_QA/wp-content/themes/WorldClothing354/images/topInsideDrop.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size:auto 85px;
 }

Comment: The background itself doesn't seem to be the problem. It's the position of the #wrapper div. In Firefox, the top is at 0px, but it is 78px in Chrome. No idea yet what causes the difference..

Comment: @MrLister Probably one of the dozens of CSS sheets...

Answer (score 0):

The margin on `#nav` is collapsing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) because its parent (`#wrapper`) has no top margin, padding, or border to contain it. A quick-and-dirty fix for your problem would be to add `padding-top: 1px;` to your `#wrapper` CSS.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you.  I am really in awe.  I am marking this as an answer, but for the sake of learning how to fish...

Comment: Sorry, I got cuttoff in the middle of typing.  

1.  How did you come up with this answer?  I would not have found that in a million years?
2.  Is there something wrong about the way this page is getting marked up that caused this problem?

Comment: Is there something I am supposed to do to mark this answered?  I cannot vote on it.

Comment: I believe the answers to your questions are found in the link that was supplied in the answer.

Comment: @DanAllen Without taking a longer look at your code, it's difficult for me to say how you might change the situation (except with the hack I suggested). But I was able to figure this out using [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), which is very similar in many ways to Firebug.

Comment: @DanAllen you can go with either answer but with my solution you just update two properties of your CSS.

Comment: @BrysonGilbert, thank you.  I made the change you posted and am running with it.  I just don't know how to indicate approval.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `margin` property of `#nav` and add `padding` to `#wrapper` equal to the height of your background image.

```css
#nav {
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper {
     padding-top: 85px;
}
```